# HOW TO USE CASE WHEN STATEMENT IN R

Tags: r

INPUT:-

```
ID   NAME    DATE     ATTENDENCE  
1   murali  2021-08-20  present  
1   murali  2021-08-21  absent  
1   murali  2021-08-22  present  
1   murali  2021-08-23  absent  
1   murali  2021-08-24  present  
1   murali  2021-08-25  absent  
1   murali  2021-08-26  present  
1   murali  2021-08-27  absent  
1   murali  2021-08-28  absent  
1   murali  2021-08-29  absent  
1   murali  2021-08-30  absent  
2   krishna 2021-08-20  absent  
2   krishna 2021-08-21  absent  
2   krishna 2021-08-22  absent  
2   krishna 2021-08-23  absent  
2   krishna 2021-08-24  absent  
2   krishna 2021-08-25  absent  
2   krishna 2021-08-26  present  
2   krishna 2021-08-27  absent  
2   krishna 2021-08-28  present  
2   krishna 2021-08-29  present  
2   krishna 2021-08-30  absent
```

OUTPUT:-

ID NAME DATE ATTENDENCE PRESENT absent
1 murali 2021-08-20 present 1 0
1 murali 2021-08-21 absent 0 1
1 murali 2021-08-22 present 1 0
1 murali 2021-08-23 absent 0 1
1 murali 2021-08-24 present 1 0
1 murali 2021-08-25 absent 0 1
1 murali 2021-08-26 present 1 0
1 murali 2021-08-27 absent 0 1
1 murali 2021-08-28 absent 0 1
1 murali 2021-08-29 absent 0 1
1 murali 2021-08-30 absent 0 1
2 krishna 2021-08-20 absent 0 1
2 krishna 2021-08-21 absent 0 1
2 krishna 2021-08-22 absent 0 1
2 krishna 2021-08-23 absent 0 1
2 krishna 2021-08-24 absent 0 1
2 krishna 2021-08-25 absent 0 1
2 krishna 2021-08-26 present 1 0
2 krishna 2021-08-27 absent 0 1
2 krishna 2021-08-28 present 1 0
2 krishna 2021-08-29 present 1 1
2 krishna 2021-08-30 absent 0 0

Comment: `table(df$NAME, df$ATTENDENCE)` (where you replace `df` with whatever your input data frame is called).

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: If your input is called `df` then the code to get your output is `table(df$NAME, df$ATTENDENCE)` - no need for `case_when`. If your input is called `INPUT` then the code is `table(INPUT$NAME, INPUT$ATTENDENCE)`

Comment: thanks ,it is working but i want to do with case_when statement

Comment: Why? Is this homework?

Comment: yes my manager gave this as assignment

Comment: `case_when` is a weird way to accomplish this task. If you want to do it in the tidyverse, then `count()` would be the natural approach (`count(df, name, attendance)` or `df %>% count(name, attendance)` (you would have to `pivot_wider` to get it into the desired output format). I can't think of a way to do it with `case_when` that doesn't seem terribly clunky. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Using case_when to solve this problem is like using a hammer to turn a screw

Comment: [Is your capslock key malfunctioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting)?

Comment: It's definitely not the best way to do it but you could start out as this question does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71065712/how-to-count-occurrences-by-day-using-dplyr/71067677#71067677 by using `case_when` to translate `present`, `absent` into binary numeric (0/1) values, then `group_by` and summarise/sum. But you'd be better off using `count` in the first place (as in my answer to that question).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

not `case_when` but it is a tidyverse alternative

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(NAME) %>% 
  count(ATTENDENCE) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ATTENDENCE,
              values_from = n)
```